# How Do Mathematicians Plot Schematics?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm unsure of whether this is the correct division for this question but I think people here might have the correct resources for this question:

Just wondering: is there a software that is most commonly used to created schematic plots for mathematical publications? I have used some built in softwares in system but I was wondering if there was a standard or really convinent way of producing accurate and visually pleasing schematic plots. What do you guys do?

Comment: What are schematic plots in the context of mathematics?

Comment: Why not ask on the [MMA site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com)?